# How to include evm chain decimals?

Tags: evm, chainspec, frontier-node-template

I tried frontier-node-template it's working fine with substrate part but showing less balance in metamask.
I used chainid and RPC it's showing 20 TEST instead of 20M Tokens
What's i am missing? How to include decimal for evm chain?

Comment: For the Substrate chain, you can set the token decimals property in `chain_spec.rs` with `let token_decimals = json!(18);` and `properties.insert("tokenDecimals".to_string(), token_decimals);` then setting `Some(properties)` in the `from_genesis` call.